# How to initialize a dictionary containing lists of dictionaries?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am starting to do a little development in C#, and I am stuck with a problem here. Usually I develop in Python where stuff like this is being implemented easily (at least for me), but I have no idea how to do that in C#:

I want to create a dictionary containing a list of dictionaries like the following using Generic Collections:

```
{ "alfred",  [ {"age", 20.0}, {"height_cm", 180.1} ],
  "barbara", [ {"age", 18.5}, {"height_cm", 167.3} ],
  "chris",   [ {"age", 39.0}, {"height_cm", 179.0} ]
}
```

I started with the following:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, double>[]> persons;
```

But then I'd like to insert the three records from above at once into persons. I am stuck with syntax errors all the way.

Anyone have a solution for me?

**Edit:**

Thank you all - I didn't expect to receive so many well thought answers in such a short time! You are great!

Comment: [Go read the manual! :)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx)

Comment: Your main problem is that you want to write python in C#. C# is mainly statically typed, and you should take advantage of that. You can use `dynamic` and something like expando object to get behavior similar to dynamically typed languages. But idiomatic C# uses static typing with classes that define your members instead of dictionaries. Your outer dictionary is fine, your inner dictionary is ugly, since it should be a class.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You could use [dictionary initializes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx). Not as elegant as Python, but could live with:

```
var persons = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>
{
    { "alfred", new Dictionary<string, double> { { "age", 20.0 }, { "height_cm", 180.1 } } },
    { "barbara", new Dictionary<string, double> { { "age", 18.5 }, { "height_cm", 167.3 } } },
    { "chris", new Dictionary<string, double> { { "age", 39.0 }, { "height_cm", 179.0 } } }
};
```

And then:

```
persons["alfred"]["age"];
```

Also notice that you need `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>` for this structure and not `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>[]>`.

Also working with such structure could be a little PITA and harm readability and compile-time type safety of the code.

In .NET it is preferred to work with strongly typed objects, like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public double Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double HeightCm { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
var persons = new[]
{
    new Person { Name = "alfred", Age = 20.0, HeightCm = 180.1 },
    new Person { Name = "barbara", Age = 18.5, HeightCm = 180.1 },
    new Person { Name = "chris", Age = 39.0, HeightCm = 179.0 },
};
```

and then you could use LINQ to fetch whatever information you need:

```
double barbarasAge = 
    (from p in persons
     where p.Name == "barbara"
     select p.Age).First();
```

To be noted of course that using collections would not be as fast as a hashtable lookup but depending on your needs in terms of performance you could also live with that.

Comment: +1 May I suggest using a type alias such as `using MyDict = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, double>;`?

Comment: @Ani, yes you may. Actually I would suggest using a `Person` class instead of dictionaries.

Comment: May I suggest not using a type alias? I prefer just `using System.Collections.Generic`.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do this:

```
 Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>> dict =  
                       new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string, double>>() {
     {"alfred",new Dictionary<string,double>() {{"age",20.0},{"height":180.1}}},
     {"barbara",new Dictionary<string,double>() {{"age",18.5},{"height": 167.3}}}
 };
```

You would be better off using typed person though, or an [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) to give typed syntax access to the dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, Person> dict = new Dictionary<string,Person>() {
         {"alfred",new Person { age=20.0 ,height=180.1 }},
         {"barbara",new Person { age=18.5,height=167.3 }}
     };
```

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the more elegant way to do this in c#, **to avoid this use of the Dictionary**, c# has better options than that,

is to create a **class** (or struct) like `Person`

```
public class Person 
{
    public Person() { }

    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
    public double Height {get;set;}
}
```

and put those objects in a generic list or collection that implements [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx)

```
public List<Person>;
```

And use [Linq to get the person you want](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336760#WhereSimple1)

```
var personToLookfor =
    from p in people
    where p.Name == "somename"
    select p;
```

Comment: why is "avoiding ... the Dictionary" class a desirable goal?

Comment: Because the OP's problem is not about a key-value relation

Comment: Is nesting dictionaries inherently a bad thing?

Comment: Dictionaries are a bit faster and use less memory than a full blown class.