# Array of arrays with string keys in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am new to C# but i have a background in PHP. Working some basic stuff in C# i came across some odd thing for me. I want to create an array of arrays in C# with string keys that hold another array of string keys. If I had to do this in PHP it whould look like this:

```
$workers = array("John" => array("salary" => 1000, "bonus" => 200), 
                 "Michal" => array("salary" => 1500, "bonus" => 0)
           );
```

Digging into C# I found some answers like hashtable or dictionary, but it made me more confused.

Comment: Wow thx all for the answers, I never thought i whould get an answer so fast. I was thinking, if I am lucky il see something latter tonight when i get home. All of you are awsome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# is not like PHP in that it is not loose so you need to declare exactly what the array (hashtable if you want string keys) can hold. Meaning if you wish to have an array of arrays, then the parent array needs to be told that it holds arrays and cannot hold anything else.

This has basicly been answered here:

[How to initialize a dictionary containing lists of dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460702/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-containing-lists-of-dictionaries)

Comment: This is exacly what I was looking for, even though the rest of the answeres are also usefull to me. Gives me more info to experiment on. Thank you so much.

Comment: and how about `dynamic` types that are inferred from usage only at run-time. And it's possible to create array of `anonymous type` too.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in .NET doesn't have key-value pairs, so you would need to use a different collection for that, like a dictionary.

The closest to your PHP code would be a dictionary of dictionaries, however a dictionary of custom classes work be more in line with how data is handled in C#.

The class:

```
public class Worker {
  public int Salary { get; set; }
  public int Bonus { get; set; }
}
```

The dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Worker> workers = new Dictionary<string, Worker>();
workers.Add("John", new Worker{ Salary = 1000, Bonus = 200 });
workers.Add("Michal", new Worker{ Salary = 1500, Bonus = 0 });
```

This allows you to locate a worker by name, and then access the properties. Example:

```
string name = "John";
Worker w = workers[name];
int salary = w.Salary;
int bonus = w.Bonus;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a class for your object Worker:

```
public class Worker
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }
    public int Bonus { get; set; }

    public Worker(string name, double salary, int bonus)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Salary = salary;
        this.Bonus = bonus;
    }
}
```

Then create a List of workers:

```
List<Worker> workers = new List<Worker>() { 
    new Worker("John", 1000, 200),
    new Worker("Michal", 1500, 0)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in c# is something like this :

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }
    public int Bonus { get; set; }

    public Employee(string name, double salary, int bonus)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Bonus = bonus;
        this.Salary = salary;
    }
}
```

And create dictionary :

```
Dictionary<string, Employee> emps = new Dictionary<string, Employee>();
emps.Add("Michal", new Employee("Michal", 1500, 0));
emps.Add("John", new Employee("John", 1000, 200));
```

Or sometimes you may wish to use `dynamic` and `anonymous type` for our employees rather then strong type (such as `Employee`) :

```
        var John = new { Salary = 1000, Bonus = 200 };
        var Michal = new { Salary = 1500, Bonus = 0 };

        var dict = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()
        {
            {"John", John},
            {"Michal", Michal},
        };

        Console.WriteLine(dict["John"].Bonus);
```

output : 200